# SVG in Mobile Screen

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a responsive SVG Path using a `<path>` SVG element. However, I having trouble getting it to work.

I want to change only (#Layer_2) width to match the screen size. I don't want to change other layers/ g's width or height.

I've tried writing CSS for each g's but it's not working.

The SVG shape I'm using was exported from *Adobe Illustrator*.

Here's the SVG codes

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 1440 360" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1440 360;" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Layer_2">
    <rect id="XMLID_4_" x="174.5" y="179.4" width="1095.8" height="180.6"/>
</g>
<g id="Layer_3">
    <path id="XMLID_5_" d="M0,360c0,0,1-180.6,180.5-180.6L180,360H0z"/>
</g>
<g id="Layer_4">
    <path id="XMLID_7_" d="M1259.2,180c0,0,180.8,0.1,180.8-180v360h-180.8V180z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Here's [reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMxQT.png) of what I want with the screen size decrease,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, stretching a part of an SVG like that is not possible with pure SVG.  You can, of course, aways do it by modifying the SVG with Javascript.

However there is a hacky way to do it as long as your SVG design meets certain criteria.  The main criteria is that at least on of your end parts is solid, and completely covers your "stretchy" middle part.

In your case that is true.  Your right end part will completely cover your middle rectangle.

Here's a working example. Try going full screen and resizing the window to test the stretch works.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewBox="0 0 1440 360">
  <defs>
    <!-- Position the "right" end part so that its RHS is at 0.
         Then when we later position at <use x="100%", it will stick to the right end of the SVG. -->
    <path id="End_Right" d="M1259.2,180c0,0,180.8,0.1,180.8-180v360h-180.8V180z" transform="translate(-1440, 0)"/>
  </defs>

  <!-- Left end part is unchanged -->
  <path id="End_Left" d="M0,360c0,0,1-180.6,180.5-180.6L180,360H0z"/>
  <!-- Middle part modified. It starts at the same place (x=174.5), but we make its width 100%
       so that it is guaranteed to extend at least as far as the RHS of the SVG.  It will likely
       extend past the RH end of the SVG, but we won't see it because overflow is hidden. -->
  <rect id="Middle" x="174.5" y="179.4" width="100%" height="180.6"/>
  <!-- Show the right end part. It will stick to the RH side of the SVG for the reason explained above. -->
  <use xlink:href="#End_Right" x="100%" y="0"/>
</svg>
```

If you don't want it to enlarge in height, just stretch in width, you'll need to get rid of the `viewBox` and use the SVG at it's designed height. In this case that is 360px;

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="100%" height="360">
  <defs>
    <!-- Position the "right" end part so that its RHS is at 0.
         Then when we later position at <use x="100%", it will stick to the right end of the SVG. -->
    <path id="End_Right" d="M1259.2,180c0,0,180.8,0.1,180.8-180v360h-180.8V180z" transform="translate(-1440, 0)"/>
  </defs>

  <!-- Left end part is unchanged -->
  <path id="End_Left" d="M0,360c0,0,1-180.6,180.5-180.6L180,360H0z"/>
  <!-- Middle part modified. It starts at the same place (x=174.5), but we make its width 100%
       so that it is guaranteed to extend at least as far as the RHS of the SVG.  It will likely
       extend past the RH end of the SVG, but we won't see it because overflow is hidden. -->
  <rect id="Middle" x="174.5" y="179.4" width="100%" height="180.6"/>
  <!-- Show the right end part. It will stick to the RH side of the SVG for the reason explained above. -->
  <use xlink:href="#End_Right" x="100%" y="0"/>
</svg>
```

**How this works**

If we colour the three parts and make them translucent, you will probably able to understand better what is happening.  The middle yellow part is extending all the way to the end of the SVG, but the right end part covers it so you can't tell.

```css
#End_Left {
  fill: red;
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
}

#Middle {
  fill: gold;
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
}

#End_Right {
  fill: blue;
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewBox="0 0 1440 360">
  <defs>
    <!-- Position the "right" end part so that its RHS is at 0.
         Then when we later position at <use x="100%", it will stick to the right end of the SVG. -->
    <path id="End_Right" d="M1259.2,180c0,0,180.8,0.1,180.8-180v360h-180.8V180z" transform="translate(-1440, 0)"/>
  </defs>

  <!-- Left end part is unchanged -->
  <path id="End_Left" d="M0,360c0,0,1-180.6,180.5-180.6L180,360H0z"/>
  <!-- Middle part modified. It starts at the same place (x=174.5), but we make its width 100%
       so that it is guaranteed to extend at least as far as the RHS of the SVG.  It will likely
       extend past the RH end of the SVG, but we won't see it because overflow is hidden. -->
  <rect id="Middle" x="174.5" y="179.4" width="100%" height="180.6"/>
  <!-- Show the right end part. It will stick to the RH side of the SVG for the reason explained above. -->
  <use xlink:href="#End_Right" x="100%" y="0"/>
</svg>
```